# How to calculate percentage for each row using azure stream analytics?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I'm getting data in real-time from NSE(national stock exchange) through the event hub to stream analytics like the following format:

```
 [{symbol: 'HCLTECH',
   openPrice: '1,097.00',
   highPrice: '1,125.00',
   lowPrice: '1,092.30',
   ltp: '1,122.80'},
 { symbol: 'BPCL',
   openPrice: '342.00',
   highPrice: '351.45',
   lowPrice: '337.50',
   ltp: '350.45'
 }]
```

as you can in json that, open price - starting price for today,
                         ltp        - current price
if open price is 100 and ltp is 150 then change is 50%
how can I do this for all rows, using azure stream analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division feature is not found in the [Mathematical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/mathematical-functions-azure-stream-analytics),so you have to calculate it by yourself with [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) in ASA.

UDF:

```
function main(arg1, arg2) {
    var f = parseFloat((arg2-arg1)/arg1);    
    if (isNaN(f)) {   
     return '0%';    
    }          
    f = Math.round(f*100)/100;  
    return f*100+"%";        
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT    
    udf.divCal(input.openPrice,input.ltp)
FROM input
```